# Send gzip requests with clj-http

Tags: clojure, gzip, clj-http

How do I send a gzipped request using the dakrone/clj-http client? So far I have:

```
(http/post <<REDACTED>>
           {:body (->> <<REDACTED>>
                       cheshire.core/generate-string
                       .getBytes
                       clj-http.util/gzip)
            :content-type "application/json"
            :content-encoding "gzip"
            :as :json})
```

But elasticsearch (the server in my case) is giving 500 errors `Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space`.

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW your call looks correct according to its [test](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/70df5add2a565a87d2ac79b39e90f777999babc0/test/clj_http/test/client_test.clj#L608). Does the request work without gzip?

Comment: Yep, removing the .getBytes, clj-http.util/gzip and :content-encoding "gzip" gives me a successful request.

Comment: Have you tried like in the test?  Use `clj-http.util/utf8-bytes` to be explicit with the encoding you want or add it to `.getBytes` (but then use `->` instead of `->>`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to enable HTTP compression on the server, e. g. in the Elasticsearch config:

```
http.compression: true
```

Comment: I'm able to send gzipped requests with curl. I think the problem is with my use of the library or my gzipping code.

Answer (score 0):

`:content-encoding` is not a recognized keyword for `clj-http`. Try `:header {"Content-Encoding" "gzip"}` instead.